# What is the notation for total number of rows in a matrix M?

Tags: matrices, notation

Consider a matrix M(i,j). It has n columns and m rows. How do I indicate m rows for matrix M? What is the notation?

Comment: You can write $\mathbf{M}\in S^{m\times n}$ where $S$ is whatever set your matrix entries are elements of.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski I thought the rows went first? Maybe I am a little confused.

Comment: Oh yes right. Whoops.

Comment: The most general notation is : $M_{m\times n}$

Comment: I wish to write: s = c x (number of rows in M). This is what I am looking for ...

Comment: This post was wrongly associated with another question that has nothing to do with my question ...

Comment: @MeMa the linked-question is perfectly valid as per the information provided in your question. If you have restrictions or if you require an answer to a specific question, then feel free to ask a new question with _as many details_ as possible. You can also edit the _current_ question and add all the required details. Then, reopen the question.

Comment: ok, thank you. I just posted the same question in a new envelope.